# How to paginate through API request in Postman

Tags: api, loops, postman, bigcommerce

I'm looking for some help on how to paginate through a BigCommerce API request to grab all of the orders. By default this API endpoint gives you 50 records at a time. I can add a query parameter to increase this to 250, but there is nothing in the API that says how many total orders there are. I need to keep running this request and dumping the responses to one large JSON file, so that I can upload this data. The issue is that there is not a way to know how many orders there are, so the page query parameter can't be filled in. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing or seeing anything about the API, and without knowing what languages you are familiar with, I would suggest that you could write up a small script that could be as simple as a while loop that will wait for the results and add them to a array you are saving. When there are no more results returned from the API, you know to stop the loop, and you can then save your array into a JSON document.

For example, using Node.js, you could do something like:

```
const fs = require('fs').promises;

let results = true;
let AllResults = [];

try {
  do {
      let result = await https://api-url // call api

      if (result.length > 0) AllResults.push(result)
      else results = false
  } while (!!results);

  await fs.writeFile('filename.txt', AllResults);
} catch (err) {
  errorHandler(err)
}
```

This is just quickly written example, but hopefully can provide a possible solution for you

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the orders api is still a V2 api, so it doesn't have the meta object returned by a V3 api that would give you this information.

You can find the total number of orders from the /orders/count endpoint, but that probably isn't necessary, i would just increment the `page` parameter until you get a `204 No Content` response (which will have no orders in it)